# С++ Возврат из функции по значению

Tags: c++, visual-c++, ассемблер, c++11, машинный-код

Я новичок в С++ 11, поэтому возникают подобные вопросы))

Собственно, имеем такой код:

```
struct testStruct
{
    int x = 10;
    int y = 11;
    int z = 12;
};

testStruct foo() 
{
    return testStruct();
}

int main(int _argc, char* _argv[])
{
    testStruct&& rv_ref = foo();
    rv_ref.z = 254;
    return 0;
}
```

Из которого мы при дизассемблировании получаем такой машинный код:

```
int main(int _argc, char* _argv[])
{
00007FF6996114F0  mov         qword ptr [rsp+10h],rdx  
00007FF6996114F5  mov         dword ptr [rsp+8],ecx  
00007FF6996114F9  push        rsi  
00007FF6996114FA  push        rdi  
00007FF6996114FB  sub         rsp,78h  
00007FF6996114FF  mov         rdi,rsp  
00007FF699611502  mov         ecx,1Eh  
00007FF699611507  mov         eax,0CCCCCCCCh  
00007FF69961150C  rep stos    dword ptr [rdi]  
00007FF69961150E  mov         ecx,dword ptr [_argc]  
    testStruct&& rv_ref = foo();
00007FF699611515  lea         rcx,[rsp+60h]  
00007FF69961151A  call        foo (07FF69961124Eh)  
00007FF69961151F  lea         rcx,[rsp+54h]  
00007FF699611524  mov         rdi,rcx  
00007FF699611527  mov         rsi,rax  
00007FF69961152A  mov         ecx,0Ch  
00007FF69961152F  rep movs    byte ptr [rdi],byte ptr [rsi]  
00007FF699611531  lea         rax,[rsp+38h]  
00007FF699611536  lea         rcx,[rsp+54h]  
00007FF69961153B  mov         rdi,rax  
00007FF69961153E  mov         rsi,rcx  
00007FF699611541  mov         ecx,0Ch  
00007FF699611546  rep movs    byte ptr [rdi],byte ptr [rsi]  
00007FF699611548  lea         rax,[rsp+38h]  
00007FF69961154D  mov         qword ptr [rv_ref],rax  
    rv_ref.z = 254;
00007FF699611552  mov         rax,qword ptr [rv_ref]  
00007FF699611557  mov         dword ptr [rax+8],0FEh
return 0;
00007FF69961155E  xor         eax,eax  
}
```

Обратите внимание на строки

```
00007FF69961152F  rep movs    byte ptr [rdi],byte ptr [rsi]
```

и

```
00007FF699611546  rep movs    byte ptr [rdi],byte ptr [rsi]
```

Они производят копирование данных из одного куска памяти на стеке, в другой кусок памяти на стеке.

**Так вот, зачем возвращаемое из функции foo() значение копируется на стек вызывающей функции main() ЦЕЛЫХ 2 РАЗА???**

По логике, хватило бы даже одного того участка стекового кадра, который использовался для возврата значения из функции foo(). Однако же в сгенерированном машинном коде, мы видим целых две копии возвращаемого значения!

Что интересно, если я даже уберу из кода ссылку на r-value, вот так:

```
int main(int _argc, char* _argv[])
{
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

То в сгенерированном машинном коде все равно останется копирование возвращаемого значения на стек вызывающей функции!

```
int main(int _argc, char* _argv[])
{
00007FF6747F14D0  mov         qword ptr [rsp+10h],rdx  
00007FF6747F14D5  mov         dword ptr [rsp+8],ecx  
00007FF6747F14D9  push        rsi  
00007FF6747F14DA  push        rdi  
00007FF6747F14DB  sub         rsp,48h  
00007FF6747F14DF  mov         rdi,rsp  
00007FF6747F14E2  mov         ecx,12h  
00007FF6747F14E7  mov         eax,0CCCCCCCCh  
00007FF6747F14EC  rep stos    dword ptr [rdi]  
00007FF6747F14EE  mov         ecx,dword ptr [_argc]  
    foo(127);
00007FF6747F14F2  mov         edx,7Fh  
00007FF6747F14F7  lea         rcx,[rsp+30h]  
00007FF6747F14FC  call        foo (07FF6747F114Fh)  
00007FF6747F1501  lea         rcx,[rsp+20h]  
00007FF6747F1506  mov         rdi,rcx  
00007FF6747F1509  mov         rsi,rax  
00007FF6747F150C  mov         ecx,0Ch  
00007FF6747F1511  rep movs    byte ptr [rdi],byte ptr [rsi]
return 0;
00007FF6747F1513  xor         eax,eax  
}
```

При чем в некоторых случаях сохраняется двойное копирование, как в предыдущем листинге (в этот раз я просто не поймал этот дизассемблер, от чего зависит количество копирований возвращаемого значения, не знаю)

**Так вот, зачем делать столько копий возвращаемого значения на стеке вызывающей функции???**

*Является ли это всего лишь следствием того, что современные компиляторы, как и многие другие программные продукты являются дикой, многоуровневой матрешкой и разработчики, напрмер, некоего парсера возвращаемых значений функции (не ругайте меня, нуба, если что, за подобные выражения)) совсем не в курсах о том как происходит генерация машинного кода, потому что для них это уже 100500-я абстракция. Или же это имеет некий пока непонятный для меня, сакральный смысл, реализованный в колдунстве со всеми этими r-value, x-value, const и прочей мишурой нового с++ 11, обеспечивающий, например, некие неизменяемые копии, мувы и т.д?!*

Буду очень благодарен за пояснения!

Comment: Видимо вы смотрите выхлоп компилятора без оптимизации. В дебаг сборках может быть прорва излишних и неоптимальных инструкций.

Comment: А Вы не смотрели, как другие компиляторы себя ведут? Даже с отключенными оптимизациями?

Comment: Изучать C++ через ассемблер это весьма странный путь изучения, не делайте этого.

Answer (score 1):

А это ничего, что VC++17 при компиляции дает

```
main    PROC                        ; COMDAT

; 22   :     testStruct&& rv_ref = foo();
; 23   :     rv_ref.z = 254;
; 24   :     return 0;

    xor eax, eax

; 25   : }

    ret 0
main    ENDP
```

? :)
Выходной ассемблерный код может быть... ну, несколько различным, так что...